# AJAX success event run twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hey i trying to figure it out what is wrong in code, i am using text box which checks the value entered is available in database or not (through onchange event) if value is not available it as to give the alert("Invalid Number");

As the code works fine when i open it first time once i refresh it gives me the 2 times alert massage.

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','#acccno', function () {
        var acno = $(this).val();
        var data={"acno":acno,"acccno":1};
        $.ajax({
            url:"accsav.php",
            async: false,
            type:"POST",
            data:data,
            success:function(dat){
                if(dat===''){
                    alert("Invalid  Number");
                    $("#acccno").val('');
                   // $("#acccno").focus();
                } else {
                    $("#image1").html(dat);
                }
            },
            error:function(er){
                console.log(er);
            }
        });
     });
});
```

Comment: can you try  $('#accno').on('change',function(){}); instead of $(document).on('change','#accno',.....

Comment: There is a hack add this -- e.stopImmediatePropagation(); -- in on change function(e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really a simple change that needs to be done. Once success you empty the value in the input box. Which triggers another on change event and the ajax is called again but this time with empty values. Inside the on change function you can check if the value is empty. Please find the fixed version below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('focusout','#acccno', function () {
    var acno = $(this).val();
    var data={"acno":acno,"acccno":1};

if( acno !=''){
    $.ajax({
        url:"accsav.php",
        async: false,
        type:"POST",
        data:data,
        success:function(dat){
            if(dat===''){
                alert("Invalid  Number");
                $("#acccno").val('');
               // $("#acccno").focus();
            } else {
                $("#image1").html(dat);
            }
        },
        error:function(er){
            console.log(er);
        }
    });
}
 });
});
```

Comment: This is a workaround, not a fix. Not perse bad, but the original problem still exists.

Comment: i made an edit  and changed the on change to on focus out . So that only when the field is manually updated , the function will be called. Thanks , please up vote if it helps ya !!!

Answer (score 1):

When the given account number is invalid it displays the alert message and **changes** the input to empty string, which triggers the event again and shows the alert again in this case, because the server response with an empty account number is probably also invalid. Then it changes the value again, but because it was already empty before nothing changes here and the event does not get fired again.

My suggestion: Wrap the field with a form and use the onsubmit event instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind the event to the specific element and not to the whole document, which is recommended anyway, or maybe you can try using "input" event.

quote from this site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`
>   elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the
>   user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily
>   fired for each change to an element's value.

Comment: OP is targeting a specific element by passing in a CSS-selector as a argument in the .on()-function. Maybe the element in question isn't in the DOM at runtime, so instead it makes sense to target the document.

Comment: Binding everything to the document ***is not recommended***, instead you should use the closest/fastest selector possible. If you have a `#exampleListWrap` with AJAX loaded element, use that ID, not the document!